# limit the number of pages when using @media print in css

Tags: css

how to limit the number of pages when using @media  print in css?
the second page is dispalyed as empty.is there any solution?

```css
@media print {
    
    .button-wrapper {
        display: none;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }

    @page {
        @footnote {
          display: none;
        }
    }        
    footer {
        display: none;
    }

    .confirmation {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide sample html to reproduce it?